# Prevent UIImageView from rotating with the device rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-rotation, compass-geolocation

I am doing a compass and I dont want my **uiimageview** rotate when the user rotate the device.
Is it possible to disable this?

Thanks you.

Comment: its not possible to stop but, when your device rotate you can get the rotation angle and rotate your UIImageView into back state.

Comment: @Retro not sure what that means. But anyway, you need to explain what you want more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it took me a while to work out what you actually wanted.

Your question would be better phrased something like...

> I'm trying to make a compass app. Using an image as the compass. Can I keep it pointing in the same direction when the user rotates the device.

The answer to this is yes.

You need to look at using the CoreMotion framework.

**JUST A QUICK NOTE**

By doing this you are not "preventing it from rotating". You are actually rotating the image on the screen to give the illusion that it is not rotating.

Comment: @user3800957 no worries :D

Answer (score -2):

In your app settings -> General -> Deployment Info:
Unmark what ever u want:

[image]

Comment: I think the question is not about device orientation but about creating a compass image that rotates to always point north.